# Laravel 5.1 GCM Push notification SSL error

Tags: php, laravel-5, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, ssl-certificate

I have connected `GCM` with `laravel 5.1` PushNotification through `\Zend\Http\` client.
It was working good. But suddenly it stopped working and produce some `exceptions`.

My code is like...

```
$collection = PushNotification::app('appNameAndroid')->to ( $deviceToken ); 
$collection->adapter->setAdapterParameters(['sslverifypeer' => false]);
$collection->send ( $message );
```

I also have tried the below codes but none of them are working...

```
$collection = PushNotification::app('appNameAndroid')->to ( $deviceToken ); 
$new_client = new \Zend\Http\Client(null, array(
                'adapter' => 'Zend\Http\Client\Adapter\Socket',
                'sslverifypeer' => false
));
$collection->adapter->setHttpClient($new_client); 
$collection->send ( $message );

----------------------------and-----------------------------------

$collection = PushNotification::app('appNameAndroid')->to ( $deviceToken ); 
        $collection->adapter->setAdapterParameters(array(
        'ssl'=>array(
                'verify_peer' => false,
                'verify_peer_name' => false)
));
$collection->send ( $message );
```

The exceptions are...

```
exception 'ErrorException' with message 'stream_socket_enable_crypto(): SSL     operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
error:14077102:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unsupported protocol' in C:\xampp\htdocs\activ8-webapp\api\vendor\zendframework\zend-http\src\Client\Adapter\Socket.php:281

Next exception 'Zend\Http\Client\Adapter\Exception\RuntimeException' with message 'Unable to enable crypto on TCP connection gcm-http.googleapis.com' in C:\xampp\htdocs\activ8-webapp\api\vendor\zendframework\zend-http\src\Client\Adapter\Socket.php:308
```

Answer (score 1):

Based from this [thread](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/issues/368), if your certificate doesn't match, it will fail with that error. Fix your SSL config since it's not PHP's fault. If the SSL config of the server you are connecting to is not correct, you will get an error like this. Try to replace the invalid, misconfigured or self-signed certificate with a good one. You can allow insecure connections via the `SMTPOptions` property. It's possible to do this by [subclassing the SMTP class](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Overriding-the-SMTP-class) in earlier versions, though this is not recommended. Try also changing the `app/config/email.php`: `smtp` to `mail`

Sample code snippet found on this [link](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting):

```
$mail->SMTPOptions = array(
    'ssl' => array(
        'verify_peer' => false,
        'verify_peer_name' => false,
        'allow_self_signed' => true
    )
);
```

You can also check this related links:

- [how to fix stream_socket_enable_crypto(): SSL operation failed with code 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30556773/how-to-fix-stream-socket-enable-crypto-ssl-operation-failed-with-code-1)
- [Laravel SMTP driver with TLS encryption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30714229/laravel-smtp-driver-with-tls-encryption)

Hope this helps!

Comment: I'm not using phpmail here, please saw my question. And I have tried that also in my case, but working.