# Laravel - Password Reset - Can´t Send Messages

Tags: php, laravel, email, swiftmailer

I used the artisan command "php artisan make:auth" And Users authentication and registration is working fine but for some reason the App just can't send the reset passwords email.

I was able to properly configure the env file and even receive the message; "We have e-mailed your password reset link!", but the email never reaches the recipient.

This is my env file:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=log
MAIL_HOST=smtp.liberumratings.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=website@liberumratings.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=******
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

I also tried the example below but a got this error:

> (1/1) ErrorException
>
> stream_socket_enable_crypto(): Peer certificate CN=`*.locaweb.com.br'
>   did not match expected CN=`smtp.liberumratings.com'

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.liberumratings.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=website@liberumratings.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=******
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

All my parameters are correct and I am able to send emails using the PHPMailer on the same server on another application.

Comment: The answer to this question might be of use: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30371910/phpmailer-generates-php-warning-stream-socket-enable-crypto-peer-certificate

Comment: Laravel uses swiftmailer instead of phpmailer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The encryption might be wrong. Are you using SSL?

Remove the tls and try agian. Also your answer can be found here
[Laravel SMTP driver with TLS encryption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30714229/laravel-smtp-driver-with-tls-encryption)